# Is Any Statistic Distribution which takes its graph maximum and x range as input?

Tags: math, statistics

please look at following image,
I have "p" and,"val" and "min ,max" values. I need a distribution which takes them as input.
any Idea?

[image]

Comment: There are an infinite number of distributions that can satisfy those requirements.  Pick one or specify what your other requirements might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest distribution with a given min, max and mode is the [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), for example using scipy's [`triang`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.triang.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import triang
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a, mode, b = 1, 3, 10
scale = b - a
shape = (mode - a) / scale
loc = a

x = np.linspace(a, b, 200)
ax.plot(x, triang.pdf(x, shape, loc, scale))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Note that the value of `p = pdf(mode, triang.pdf(x, shape, loc, scale))` will be `2 / (b - a)`.

A more complicated distribution would be a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) where the parameters `alpha` and `beta` can be [calculated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mode_and_concentration) from a given mode and concentration (`= alpha + beta`).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import triang, beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a, mode, b = 1, 3, 10
scale = b - a
shape = (mode - a) / scale
loc = a

x = np.linspace(a, b, 200)

for concentration in np.arange(2, 20, 3):
    alpha = shape * (concentration - 2) + 1
    bet = (1 - shape) * (concentration - 2) + 1
    ax.plot(x, beta.pdf(x, alpha, bet, loc, scale), label=concentration)
ax.legend(title='concentration')
plt.show()
```

[image: beta distribution]